# Notice: Undefined variable: nome in C:\wamp

Tags: php

```
<?php

  if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    extract($_POST);

    if($nome == '' OR strlen($nome)<4){
        echo 'Insira um nome existente';
    }elseif($sobrenome=='' OR strlen($sobrenome)<6){ 
        echo 'Insira um sobrenome existente';
    }elseif($email==''){
        echo 'Insira seu e-mail';
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[az0-9_\.\-]+@[az0-9_\.\-}*{a-z0-9_\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i",$email)){
        echo 'E-mail invalido tente outro';
    }else{

        include('../../sllapsocial/classes/DB.class.php');

        $verificar = DB::getConn()->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `email`=?");
        if($verificar->execute(array($email))){
            if($verificar->rowCount()>=1){
         echo 'Este e-mail ja existe';

     }elseif($senha=='' OR strlen($senha)<4){
        echo'Senha fraca Insira mais caracteres';
     }elseif(strtolower($capctha) <> strtolower($_SESSION['capcthaCadastro'])){
         echo 'Codigo errado';
     }else{
         $senhaInsert = sha1($senha);
         $nascimento = "$ano-$mes-$dia";
         $inserir = DB::getConn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuarios` SET `email`=?, `senha` =?, `nome`=? `sobrenome`=?, `sexo`=?, `nascimento`=?`cadastro`=NOW()");

         if($inserir->execute(array($nome,$sobrenome,$email,$senhaInsert,$nascimento,$sexo))){
        header('Location: ./');  
           }

        }

       }

    }

    }

  ?>
```

Comment: Bacco sou novo nisso o erro é o seguinte quando eu prencho o formulario e submito ele aparece esse erro de variavel e aparece 'insira um nome existente' sera q a tabela de usuarios nao esta batendo? OBRIGADO PELA ATENÇAO

Comment: Parece que você quer pegar um campo do formulário... está fazendo corretamente: `$_POST['nome_do_campo']`?

Comment: Coloque a parte do form onde é definido o campo nome.

Comment: Ele esta dando extract.

Comment: Davidjesus o @PapaCharlie já deu um pontapé inicial no problema, mas seria legal você [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar o form que está enviando os dados também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O PHP está respondendo que a variável não foi definida(Undefined variable). Use [*isset*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) para verificar se a variável foi criada.

```
if( isset( $nome ) )
{
    if( $nome == '' OR strlen( $nome ) < 4 )
    {
        echo 'menor que 4';
    }
}
```

OBS 1. `$nome == ''` e `$nome === ''` possuem resultado diferente de acordo coma tipagem da variável, veja os [*operadores*](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp).

OBS2. `strlen` não retorna o tamanho exato da string quando possuir caracteres especiais. Prefira usar [*mb_strlen*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strlen.php) para trabalhar com strings.

---

Se você quer pegar um campo do formulário, use `$_POST['nome_do_campo']`. **JAMAIS** use [*extract*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php) em dados de formulário. Imagine o cenário abaixo com um usuário injetando um `<input name="pdo" />`

```
<form method="post">
     <input name="pdo" />
</form>

$PDO = new PDO( ... );
extract($_POST);
```

Você vai perder sua instância PDO.

Comment: Por padrão, `extract` tem o segundo parâmetro como `EXTR_OVERWRITE` (é isso que o torna perigoso nesses casos). No caso de dados do formulário, só seria indicado se fosse usada a flag EXTR_PREFIX_ALL combinada com um prefixo no terceiro parâmetro. Aí todas as variáveis poderiam, por exemplo, ter o prefixo $post_ em cada nome. Há também outras opções a serem consideradas em caso de colisões de nomes de variáveis, como pode ser visto [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php)

Comment: @Wallace Maxters, eu ia citar o prefixo, mas extract em dados de usuário é uma péssima pratica! Há um alerta no [*manual*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php#refsect1-function.extract-notes). Usá-la para entradas de usuário é fazer mau uso da função.

Comment: você tem razão. Inclusive um problema parecido com esse (dados vindos do usuário passados para variáveis) era o tal do `register globals`. Eu uso `extract` em casos onde tenho maior controle de dados, como  no framework laravel. Exemplo: `extract(Input::only('nome', 'email'))`

Comment: Todo cuidado é pouco com dados de usuario. Eu uso extract nos dados de conexao vindos do meu config. Se os dados forem conhecidos, realmente não há problema em usar. Se não me engano, o Laravel usa extract na view para criar as variaveis.

Comment: Sim, @Papa. Na verdade, todos os frameworks que usei até hoje fazem isso para enviar dados à view. Nesse caso, o `extract` é usado dentro de um contexto de uma função ou método (já que o include da view geralmente é feito dentro delas), e assim é mais tranquilo, pois os dados serão encapsulados ali dentro, sem conflitar com as variáveis do contexto global.