# Formulário não cadastra, nenhum nome fica gravado

Tags: php

Meu formulário não está salvando nenhum dado no banco, o que pode ser?

```
<div id="formulario">      <div align="left">
    <?php

      if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        extract($_POST);

    if(isset($nome))
        if($nome === '' OR strlen($nome)<4){
            echo 'Insira um nome existente';
        }elseif($sobrenome=='' OR strlen($sobrenome)<6){ 
            echo 'Insira um sobrenome existente';
        }elseif($email==''){
            echo 'Insira seu e-mail';
        }elseif(!preg_match("/^[az0-9_\.\-]+@[az0-9_\.\-}*{a-z0-9_\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i",$email)){
            echo 'E-mail invalido tente outro';
        }else{

            include('../../sllapsocial/classes/DB.class.php');

            $verificar = DB::getConn()->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `email`=?");
            if($verificar->execute(array($email))){
                if($verificar->rowCount()>=1){
             echo 'Este e-mail ja existe';

         }elseif($senha=='' OR strlen($senha)<4){
            echo'Senha fraca Insira mais caracteres';
         }elseif(strtolower($capctha) <> strtolower($_SESSION['capcthaCadastro'])){
             echo 'Codigo errado';
         }else{
             $senhaInsert = sha1($senha);
             $nascimento = "$ano-$mes-$dia";
             $inserir = DB::getConn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuarios` SET `email`=?, `senha` =?, `nome`=? `sobrenome`=?, `sexo`=?, `nascimento`=?`cadastro`=NOW()");

             if($inserir->execute(array($nome,$sobrenome,$email,$senhaInsert,$nascimento,$sexo))){
            header('Location: ./');  
               }

            }

           }

        }

        }

      ?>
  </div>
  <h3 align="left">Para ter acesso,É facil e gratis.</h3>
 <form name="cadastro" action="" method="post" >
   <div>
    <div class="inputfloat">
         <div align="left"><span>Nome</span>
         <input name="Nome" type="text" class="txtInput" value="<?php if(!empty($nome)) echo $nome; ?>" size="40"/>
         <div>

          <div class="inputfloat">
             <span>Sobrenome</span>
             <input name="Sobrenome" type="text" class="txtInput" value="<?php if(!empty($sobrenome)) echo $sobrenome; ?>" size="40"/>
             <div>

           <span class="spanHide">Seu e-mail</span>
             <input name="Seu e-mail" type="text" class="txtInput" value=" <?php  if(!empty($email)) echo $email; ?>" size="40"/>

             <span class="spanHide">Insira o e-mail novamente</span>
             <input name="Insira o e-mail novamente" type="text" class="txtInput" size="40" value=" <?php if(!empty($email)) echo $email; ?>" />

             <span class="spanHide">Senha</span>
             <input name="Senha" type="password" class="txtInput" size="40" value="<?php  if(!empty($senha)) echo $senha; ?>" />

           <span class="spanHide">Data de nascimento</span>
             <select name="Dia">
               <option value="">Dia</option>
               <?php 
         for($d=1;$d<=31;$d++){
             $zero = ($d<10) ? 0 : '';
             if(!empty($dia)==$zero.$d){
             echo '<option selected="selected" value="',$zero,$d,'">',$zero,$d,'</option>';
             }else{
             echo '<option value="',$zero,$d,'">',$zero,$d,'</option>';
             }

         }

      ?>

             </select>

             <select name="Mes">
               <option value="">M&ecirc;s</option>
               <?php
       $meses = array('','janeiro','fevereiro','março','abril','maio','junho','julho','agosto','setembro','outubro','novembro','dezembro');
       for($m=1;$m<=12;$m++){
       $zero = ($m<10) ? 0 : '';
       if($zero.$m == $meses){
        echo '<option selected="selected"value="',$zero,$m,'">',$meses[$m],'</option>';
       }else{
            echo '<option "value="',$zero,$m,'">',$meses[$m],'</option>';
       }
       }
      ?>

             </select>

             <select name="Ano">
               <option value="">Ano</option>
               <?php
      for($a=date('Y');$a>=(date('Y')-100);$a--){
          if(!empty($ano)){
              echo '<option selected"selected" value="',$a,'">',$a,'</option>';
          }else{
              echo '<option value="',$a,'">',$a,'</option>';      
        }
      }
      ?>

             </select>

             <span class="spanHide">Sou do sexo</span>
             <select name="sexo">
               <option <?php if(!empty($sexo) == 'masculino') echo'selected"selected"'; ?> value="masculino" >Masculino</option> 
               <option <?php if(!empty($sexo) == 'feminino') echo'selected"selected"'; ?>value="feminino" >Feminino</option> 
             </select>         
    </div>
    <div class="captchafloat">
             <div align="left"><img src="../site/captcha.php" /></div>
    </div>

         <div class="inputFloat">
           <div align="left"><span>Digite o código acima:</span>
             <input class="txtInput" type="text" name="captcha"  />
             <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="SubmitContinue" name="Continue" />
        </form>
    </div><!--formulario-->
```

Comment: Olá David, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor tome mais cuidado na formatação das perguntas (você sempre pode [edit] para melhorar). Além disso, tente incluir mais informações para ajudar os outros a responder. Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? Você tentou algum tipo de debug? Tem alguma pista? Etc. Quanto mais você disser, mais chance você tem de conseguir uma resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: sim ja tentei depurar mais nao obteu nenhum resultado como se esse codigo nao existe no formulario

Comment: Comece por colocar os campos dos forms todos em minúscula, pois você está misturando tudo na hora de usar as variáveis. Outra coisa, como já recomendado em outras ocasiões, suma com esse `extract` do seu código e use declaração direta `$nome = $_POST['nome'];` etc. Acho que este é um bom começo para avançar no código.

Comment: Bacco infelismente nao funcionou esse método esta aparecendo Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\wamp\www\redesocial\estilos\index.php on line 68

Comment: Isso é bom sinal. Um aviso de que nao foi nenhum campo 'nome' no form.

Comment: Bacco alterei tudo mais continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: é continuação [dessa aqui?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32652/notice-undefined-variable-nome-in-c-wamp-aonde-esta-por-favor)

Comment: sim mais essa é outra conta que perdi a senha

Comment: Cuidado com o atributo `name` dos input's, eles não são para colocar mensagem, são o nome dos parâmetros enviados no `POST`.

Comment: Se você der um insert com dados definidos (`$inserir->execute(array('nome' , 'sobrenome' ...) ) `) eles são gravados no DB ou não?

Comment: nao PAPA charlie eu coloquei o nome e sobrenome em letras maiusculas e funcionou :) agora o problema é oemail Notice: Undefined variable: Email in

Comment: Siga a resposta do @perdeu, e se a questão foi resolvida, marque a resposta.

Comment: PESSOAL RESOLVI ESSE LADO agora esta dando o seguinte erro Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'redeocial' inconnue' in C:\wamp\www\redesocial\classes\DB.class.php on line 6
( ! )
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'redesocial' inconnue in C:\wamp\www\redesocial\classes\DB.class.php on line 6
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0029 157776 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 0.0049 163328 DB::getConn( ) ..\index.php:82
3 0.0049 163752 __construct ( ) ..\DB.class.php:6

Comment: Ou o nome da database está errado ou ela não existe, teste direto no banco o comando: `show databases`. Qualquer coisa crie uma nova perguntar descrevendo o problema e o que já tento fazer para resolve-lo.

Comment: @perdeu database esta funcionando direito , estou seguindo o conselho anterior do Bacco tirei o extract() e adicionei $nome = $_POST['nome'];

Answer (score 2):

1 - Tome cuidado ao digitar nomes de campos/variáveis no html/php `Nome` é diferente de `nome`, veja no seu form como está definição:

```
<input name="Nome" type="text"
```

No php depois do [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) ele vai virar `$Nome` e não `$nome`.

```
if(isset($nome))
```

2- sql

Parecer ser erro de sintaxe no insert:

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios` SET
 `email`=?,
 `senha` =?,
 `nome`=? <---- falta uma virgula
 `sobrenome`=?,
 `sexo`=?,
 `nascimento`=? <---- aqui também
 `cadastro`=NOW()
```

Sempre que o mysql retornar o código `1064` sempre é algum erro de sintaxe como nome de coluna/tabela escrito errado ou aspas em lugares errados.

A mesnagem de erro é parecida como:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

[Lista dos códigos  de erro mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_parse_error)

[Sintaxe ao alternativa do insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)